# looping over the array of structs and putting values in xml

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I have a shopping cart with item values stored in an array of structures. Those values are passed into the xml. I want to loop over the xml. I know how to loop over structures and arrays, but how do I populate values in XML?

The `lineitem` will be the one where I need a loop.

```
<lineItems>
  <lineItem>
    <itemId>1</itemId>
    <name>vase</name>
    <description>Cannes logo </description>
    <quantity>18</quantity>
    <unitPrice>45.00</unitPrice>
  </lineItem>
</lineItems>
```

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion? I would be tempted just to build an XML string, save it in a `<cfsavecontent>`, then parse it into an XML variable.

Comment: using latest version, but that is a requirement to loop over and put values inside an xml code, the code is already a part of `cfsavecontent` and parsed later

Comment: You need to show what you have tried already.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you want to loop the xml data in lineItem and the xml datas are in savecontent as you mentioned above like example ,

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myXmlData">
    <lineItems>
        <lineItem>
            <itemId>1</itemId>
            <name>vase</name>
            <description>Cannes logo </description>
            <quantity>18</quantity>
            <unitPrice>45.00</unitPrice>
      </lineItem>
      <lineItem>
            <itemId>2</itemId>
            <name>vase2</name>
            <description>Cannes logo2 </description>
            <quantity>20</quantity>
            <unitPrice>90.00</unitPrice>
      </lineItem>
    </lineItems>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Your xml datas are in savecontent so you have the parse the content first and based on your tag you can made a search operations.Then you can do a loop over the xmlChildren like itemId,Name,quantity etc..

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset myXmlContent = XMLParse(myXmlData)>
    <cfset mySearchContent = xmlsearch(myXmlContent,'lineItems/lineItem')>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(mySearchContent)#" index="i">
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(mySearchContent[i].XmlChildren)#" index="j">
            #mySearchContent[i].XmlChildren[j].xmlName# --- #mySearchContent[i].XmlChildren[j].xmlText#<br/>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Make sure, Here you are xml datas are in savecontent so that we need to parse and search it then do a loop. But if your xml contents are saved as some xml file you no need to parse and search it. You can directly read that file by using

Then you can get the list of line items values by using

```
 <cffile action='read' variable='myXml'>
    <cfset myData= myxml.lineItem >
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(myData.XmlChildren)#" index="i">

      Do your logic here. !
    <cfloop>
```

I hope it's helpful to you. Thanks.

Comment: hi, thnks for the information, i think i am looking for an opposite, i have the arguments as arrayofstructs and want to add that into the xml